# How to MapFrom a collection? Auto mapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a linq to sql object that has some references to some other tables

I am trying to map it to a vm but nothing ever gets captures.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, G>();


// A is the linq to sql object
A.MyList // this is a collection that I am trying to get the value out of A.MyList.Id

// G is my View Model
public class G
{
   public string AMyListId {get; set;}

}


 vm = Mapper.Map<List<A>, List<G>>(aListOfAFromDb);
```

This always comes back from null. I thought I would have to do it manually so I tried

`Mapper.CreateMap<A, G>().ForMember(dest => dest.AMyList , opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>????))`;

but since I am getting it from a list it won't give any of the properties to choose from.

**Edit**

I realized that I should not have a list of "MyList" it should be a one to one. I still am having problems trying to do what I want to do.

I have this

Mapper.CreateMap();

```
A.Vip.UserId // again my linq object is A

// G is my View Model
public class G
{
   public string IsVip {get; set;}

}


 vm = Mapper.Map<List<A>, List<G>>(aListOfAFromDb);

 Mapper.CreateMap<A, G>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsVip, opt => opt.AddFormatter<VipFormatter>());


public class VipFormatter : IValueFormatter
    {
        public string FormatValue(ResolutionContext context)
        {
            bool value = (bool)context.SourceValue;

            if (value)
            {
                return "Yes";
            }


            return "No";

        }
    }
```

yet nothing every gets bound. I am not sure why. Do I have to do change my property to "AVipUserId"? Or somehow tell it to map?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense to me... if A contains a list, and G contains the ID for an item in the list, then you should be mapping from A to List<G>, no?   (I mean, you have many items to one "A" and one item to one "G")   Maybe that's why you're having a hard time mapping things.

Comment: If you have a property "IsVip" in "G", maybe you should make it a bool type.  Also, can you mention the logic you're using here?  How does one realize whether "A" is a "VIP"?  Is it based on whether the A.Vip object is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, and in addition to my comment above, you don't need AutoMapper for this one:

```
List<A> dbItems;
IEnumerable<G> results = dbItems.Select(x => x.MyList.MyListID);
```

In fact, you can't map A to G, because you're going to create multiple "G" objects for each "A" object.

Let me know if I misunderstood the question here.

**UPDATE:**

I would change "G" to use a boolean property and then do the following:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, G>().ForMember(dest => dest.IsVip, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Vip == null));
```

Or, whatever logic you use to determine if it is a VIP or not.

Comment: Ya after I wrote this I began to think that it did not make sense why my relationship was a one to many. It actually should be one to one. I am still having problems though. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
List<G> items = // whatever
var result = items.Select(g => Mapper.Map<G, A>(g));
```